# Push an object to an array that comes from a 2D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble trying to push objects to an array that come from a 2D array.

```
          let blacksPosition: Array<any>;

          for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
              if (boardArray[i][j].team === "black") {
                blacksPosition.push(boardArray[i][j]);
              }
            }
          }
```

TypeScript gives me the following error:

> Variable 'blacksPosition' is used before being assigned.

But I haven't used `blacksPosition`  before. It is the first time I declare it in that line.

`boardArray` is a 2D array created with the following function:

```
function create2DArray(rows: number, cols: number): Array<Array<any>> {
  const arr = new Array(rows);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = new Array(cols);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

I then populate this 2D array with Tile objects:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      boardArray[i][j] = new Tile(i, j, col, "none");
    }
  }
```

Here is the Tile class:

```
class Tile {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  tile: Element;
  team: string;
  piece: string;
  constructor(i: number, j: number, tile: Element, team: string) {
    this.x = i;
    this.y = j;
    this.tile = tile;
    this.piece = "none";
    this.team = team;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to add those Tile objects that come from the 2D array to the blacksPosition array?

Comment: Just like error is telling you, you gave it a type but no empty array value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined a typescript definition of it but didn't give it a value or type.

```
let blacksPosition: Array<any>;
```

should be

```
let blacksPosition: Array<any> = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the variable `blacksPosition` just assign it to an empty array `let blacksPosition: Array<any> = []` and you may want to consider changing the type to `Array<Tile>` just to keep everything type safe.